# Can an if statement be written in any other way?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Well, I was going through some code and found this piece of code and am confused at statement 1.

```
vector<int> v{1,2,3,2};   
mp<int,int> m;
for(auto i : v) m[i]++;
int ans = v.size();
for(auto i : v){
    ans = min(ans, m[i] + 1 - (v.front() == i) - (v.back() == i)); //statement 1
    }
```

The logic behind statement 1 is that **if v contains element i in the front or the end then subtract 1 from the occurrence of i in map.** It somehow is working correctly but how? I haven't seen such type of implementation of ***if*** before. Can someone please help **how statement 1 if considering (v.front() == i) and (v.back() == i) as an if statement without mentioning any if keyword.**

Answer (score 1):

The expression `v.front() == i` evaluates to a `bool` that's either `true` or `false`.

A bool can be implicitly converted to an `int` with the value `1` or `0`.

This is the same as when doing `if (v.front() == i)`. The expression `v.front() == i` is again a bool `true` or `false`.